# How to create a counter/stopwatch in Psychopy

Tags: psychopy

I am learning how to create Psychology experiments using Psychopy or OpenSesame. Currently, I am trying to create a Psychomotor Vigilance Task where a counter/stopwatch will appear and the participants have to press a button to stop it. How do I create this counter/stopwatch?

Please point me in the general direction and try not to provide me with the answers since I want to try to figure it out myself. Thanks!

Comment: For PsychoPy, an answer will require that you specify if you are using the Builder or Coder approach.

Comment: I would prefer to use the Builder approach. But I don't think that is possible? So I can use the Coder approach as well.

Comment: Using Builder is certainly possible, and would allow you to implement Jon's answer as below. Even simpler, you could just put `$str(round(t, 1))` in the text field of a text stimulus, and set to update on every frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide an image to represent the clock face and another to represent the hand and then change the orientation of the hand (using set every frame) according to time (ori set to $t*6 would rotate 360deg every 60s).
Tips:

- make your image for the hand transparent on areas where you want the clock face to be visible and position it in your image so that the *base* of the hand is in the centre of the image
- you could give your hand a 'ticking' appearance by rounding the orientation